# Can't access midiox COM interface from other folders

Tags: batch-file, com, wsh

I have a script using the midiox COM interface, and it works fine when located in the midiox install path, in the "WSH" folder, but when I moved this script to a folder in My Documents (so I could add it to my synced files), suddenly it appears I can't access the COM interface anymore because obtaining the `mox` variable (the main midiox object) now results in the error:

```
Could not create object named "Midiox.MoxScript.1".
```

which is referring to this line in the script:

```
var mox = WScript.CreateObject("Midiox.MoxScript.1");
```

I tried copying all of the files from the midiox install path over to My Documents (keeping the same folder structure) and I still get this error.

EDIT 15-01-14:

To eliminate the possibility that this is caused by not running either the cmd prompt or cscript.exe in 32 bit mode, I edited my batch file like so:

```
@echo off
set "SystemPath=%windir%\sysWOW64"
ECHO inside LAUNCHPAD_Polling_14-09-14
ECHO.
:RELOAD_SCRIPT
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cscript.exe C:\Users\Chris\Documents\MEGA\repos\LP_DJM_Script\LAUNCHPAD_Polling_14-09-14.js
ECHO.
ECHO.
:PROMPT
set /p UserInput= Press "Enter" to reload. ("n" to exit)
IF "%UserInput%"=="n" (
    GOTO :EXIT
) Else (
    GOTO :RELOAD_SCRIPT
)
:EXIT
```

I still get the same error.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I got it.  I had put a copy of cscript.exe in the script folder and set it to "Run as Admin" because I couldn't figure out how to get cscript to run as admin when it was called from the system32 directory.  But when I copied all the files to another directory, the copy of cscript.exe didn't automatically set itself to "Run as Admin" - which denied me access to the midiox COM interface.

Comment: Why do you have a copy of cscript.exe?

Comment: so I could set it to run as admin.. seemed easier than trying to figure out how to get windows to do it... but I could be wrong.

Comment: You can just as well make an Explorer shortcut to C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cmd.exe -c <batch-file> that runs as administrator.  The check-box is in the dialog that appears when you click the "Advanced..." button of the shortcut.  Its child processes, such as cscript.exe, will run with the same credentials, so you don't have to setup run as administrator as a compatibility shim. BTW, that downvote is not mine.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, that component is a 32-bit in-process component, which requires you to run a 32-bit application to be able to create instances of it.

You're running the 64-bit version of cscript.exe (C:\Windows\System32\cscript.exe) instead of the 32-bit version (C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cscript.exe).

If you're running from cmd.exe, the cscript.exe that runs (without providing a full path) is the one of the bitness of the cmd.exe you're running.  So, if you're executing your script from a batch file, you may instead run the 32-bit version of cmd.exe.

Comment: Note that your change to %SYSTEMPATH% is almost innocuous, as what counts when invoking cscript.exe without a full path is %PATH%.  Anyway, I re-read your question and it seems to be related only to the current path, and not to process bitness, unless you're not providing enough details.

Comment: the reason I set the path was to try and get the 32-bit version of cmd to run... which I'm honestly not sure I accomplished or not (in case that would have any affect).  Yes, current path seems to be doing something to this script... and idk what.  Why would this variable be accessible in a folder located in Program Files(x86) but not in My Documents?  I appreciate the help so far, thank you.

Comment: You have to start the correct cmd.exe upfront, setting an environment variable won't change which version you're running.  Anyway, I think you need to contact the component's authors or maintainers to help you with this.

Comment: Yeah I did contact the author but they haven't gotten back to me :\  I figured maybe this could be quickly explained by someone familiar with COM but perhaps it's component-specific?  I tried to find exactly how to set which cmd.exe gets run by a batch file and setting the path seemed like the correct way... I'll look for an alternative so I can rule that out.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: If you're in a 64bit client then you can still load a 32-bit COM object? (Windows will create a 32-bit apartment for it in another process and then do cross-apartment communication).

Comment: No, COM won't do that automatically, for that you must configure a surrogate.

Comment: To run the 32-bit cmd.exe, create a shortcut in Explorer to C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cmd.exe and run it.

Comment: right, but in the context of this question the tricky part would be getting a batch script to run the 32 bit cmd, at least IMO (btw this is no longer needed since I figured out the problem)